# Website works without the www prefix

Tags: iis-7

I am working on IIS for the first time. My website only works without the www prefix. If i enter: [this link](http://example.com) it works fine but if i enter with www [as in here](http://www.example.com) it returns "File not found". The cname record already exists.

Comment: `The cname record already exists.` So it gets to the right IP. But HTTP is a special protocol, it also sends the hostname in its requests. Which means that you will need to configure your webserver to also answer for another destination (the one with www prefixed)

Answer (score 2):

The host name portion of the URL is included separately in the HTTP request, and is used by the web server to select the virtual host that should be used to service the request.

Additionally, there is nothing magical about the  `www.` prefix; as far as the web server is concerned, `www.example.com` and `example.com` are two entirely separate virtual hosts.

What you need to do is add a separate host name that either is an alias to the existing one, or a redirection host. I *very strongly* recommend that you do the latter, but am including both for completeness.

## Alias (quick but dirty):

- Open IIS Manager
- Expand the host node
- Expand the "Sites" node
- Locate the web site node for your web site, right-click on it, and pick *Edit bindings*
- In the *Site bindings* dialog, click *Add*
- Select the correct type, IP address and enter the correct port. Enter the host name (`www.example.com`) in the provided text box. Click *OK* and *Close*.
- Verify that the configuration works as intended

After making these changes, the two names will function identically, but will be considered distinct by any clients.

## Redirection (recommended):

- Open IIS Manager
- Expand the host node
- Right-click on the "Sites" node and click *Add website*
- Configure the web site as appropriate, and point it at an empty root directory. Give it the host name that currently does not work.
- Select the newly configured site in the sidebar
- Open *HTTP Redirect* (you will find it under the *IIS* category in the *Features View*)
- Configure redirection to the canonical host name, using *Permanent (301)* status, and *Apply* the changes

This should cause any requests that come to the redirection host name to be automatically redirected to the corresponding location at the canonical host name. This ensures that search engines don't see two identical sites at different URLs, which is often seen as a bad sign. Using *Permanent* redirections means that any clients should cache the redirection response, saving them a few steps in getting to your site in the future thus improving performance for returning visitors.